# offset[[i]] error when doing binary logistic regression with mgcv GAM

Tags: r, regression, logistic-regression, gam, mgcv

I'm trying to fit a generalized additive model with a binary response, using the code:

```
library(mgcv)
m = gam(y~s(x1)+s(x2), family=multinom(K=2), data=mydata)
```

Below is a part of my data (total sample size is 443) :

```
mydata[1:3,]
   y       x1        x2
1  1 12.55127 0.2553079
2  1 12.52029 0.2264185
3  0 12.53868 0.2183521
```

But I receive this error:

```
Error in offset[[i]] : attempt to select less than one element
```

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, for binary response, why not use `family = binomial()`?

Secondly, if you want to test `multinom`, set `K = 1`, because categories are coded **from 0** to `K`. See `?multinom`. **However, you need to pass in a list of model formulae, for `multinom` family**. Even if `K = 1`, you would need a length-1 list. Use `list(y ~ s(x1) + s(x2))`.